# A query for SE Data Explorer to find our most popular software

Tags: support, data-explorer

Now that we are in public beta, we can be queried against using the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/queries).
I've noticed that some software is the answer to man different questions.
For example [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

With a little bit of simple natural language processing, (probably some hacky regexs)
it should be possible to determine which product is being recommended in each answer,
and thus to run a query against all answers to find which products show up multiple times.

I think it would be pretty cool.

Further things we could do, once we have a programitic way of identify programs the answer speaks of is generate (on say users personal websites, not on SE) Program Lists, linking to there recommendations.
Eg list of Image Editors.

Comment: I've thought of making something that would look for links to the same domain repeated multiple times, that would probably work here.

Comment: That proably would yes, because most links that are not to programs aren't going to show up more than once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was kinda bored, and thus decided to try to do this. I couldn't find an easy way to do it with SEDE, so I hacked together a thing in Python. It's [on GitHub](https://github.com/Undo1/Torch).

Here are the results (this can, and probably will, be made better):

```
6 x http://notepad-plus-plus.org/
6 x http://www.gimp.org/
5 x http://handbrake.fr/
5 x http://www.autohotkey.com/
5 x http://www.ffmpeg.org/
5 x http://www.irfanview.com/
5 x http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
5 x http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/
5 x http://www.sublimetext.com/
5 x http://www.virtualdub.org/
4 x http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/
4 x http://brackets.io/
4 x http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs
4 x http://getgreenshot.org/
4 x http://gitlab.org/
4 x http://jdownloader.org/
4 x http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/
4 x http://www.code42.com/crashplan/
4 x https://filezilla-project.org/
4 x https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/
```

Note that I'm only showing links that have more than three occurrences. Anyone that wants to contribute can fork [the repo](https://github.com/Undo1/Torch) and make a pull request!

**Edit**: I added duplicate detection, now the same link in an answer more than once only counts once. You can see the old, non-dupe-detecting, results [in the revision history](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/821/1).

Comment: Cool! When SR becomes more popular than SO (maybe in 6 months?), this could be used to notice spam: if superclock.com has not been linked to in the past, but suddenly gets linked from 10 questions in a day, then it might be spam.